# Can I get Django model objects as singletons?

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I call `Models.get()` for the same id it returns different Python objects:

```
print(Book.objects.get(id=1) is Book.objects.get(id=1))
>>> False
```

I wonder if it is possible to change this behavior, maybe with some custom Model Manager. It could internally store some registry for all retrieved objects and override `get_queryset()` to make it use objects from this registry if they have already been retrieved.

**Why do it can be helpful**

I have a model `ServerCredentials` which stores login and password. I have multiple consumers that connect using the same credentials. Since only one connection to server is allowed, it would be convenient to store transient connection information (e.g. auth token) as a field of `ServerCredentials` object, but not in database. If model objects could be singletons, consumers could easily share auth tokens just by using a field of `ServerCredentials`. Without it, I have to make some registry manually, but I fell that it should be done on `ModelManager's` side.

1. Is it a possible to cache objects in a registry on `ModelManager's` side?
2. Is it a good idea?
3. Are there implementations for that?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using the `is` operator instead of checking equality with `==`? The latter works, and seems it would do what you want. `is` is a test for object identity, not equality.

Comment: @solarissmoke but I need object equality, because I want them to share non-database fields. E.g. `Book.objects.get(id=1).some_field = "foo"; assert(Book.objects.get(id=1).some_field=="foo")` without saving to database

Answer (score 2):

The manager of a model is a regular instance of its respective class, so you could implement some kind of registry. However, this registry would be unique per process. In production, your application is usually run by a server starting multiple processes e.g. uwsgi (or even run on multiple machines).

If you want to make transient data available in your whole application, you can use Django's caching facilities with an in-memory store like Memcached or Redis.

Comment: Unique per process is ok, since my app is not a multiprocess one :) So, should I create some `CachedManager(models.Manager)`, override `get_queryset()` and use some custom `QuerySet` class there that makes caching? As soon as I understand, objects must be put in cache in `__iter__` of this custom `QuerySet` as soon it is the place where they are retrieved. @Daniel Hepper , is the ides correct?

Comment: @sckol I think my answer was unclear, I‘ve reworded it

Comment: In my particular case it is only one process, because the singleton registry is only needed for a management task (single background data download process) which is never started by a HTTP request. But your answer made me clear why there is no easy solution for that - in general case it should care about sharing the registry between processes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read a little about how apache/nginx handle processes for each request since even if you can use the singleton pattern it won't work since there can be multiple processes running at the same time each for a different request and each of that process will have it's own singleton/cache/registry in memory. One way to achieve this per process caching is described below.

What we do in our system to cache data is to use STATIC variable on the class itself to CACHE data which works well since its stored per session depending how your http server is configured(This will only be cached per process).

```
Class SomeModel(models.Model):
    CACHE_DATA = {} # you can use any other container but dicts are best if its keyable
    # write functions to populate this cache and read from this cache
    def populate_cache():
        # populate only its empty
        if SomeModel.is_cache_empty(key):
           # populate the Cache here

    def is_cache_empty(key):
        if key not in SomeModel.CACHE_DATA:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def read_data_from_cache():
        # read based on key or some other you may use a linear search for a list e.g.
```

Now you can use this cache to read data since the data will only be read once populating the cache you may also refresh the cache if it's needed.

You will have to use memcache or redis as suggested by other answer to accomplish your exact need(Same cache for all processes).

Comment: Do you call `populate_cache` manually each time when you retrieve an object? Above in comments I made a proposal: create some CachedManager(models.Manager), override get_queryset() and use some custom QuerySet class there that makes caching. How do you think, is it a correct approach? Per process caching is okay.

Comment: you only call populate_cache if it's not yet filled. I usually key the cache based on a unique value(e.f username) to see if its cached but you can check if its empty or search for a value in the cache it largely depends on your table structure. So you can make a function is_cache_ empty () to determine if its empty. And yes you can use it on a ObjectManager too just make sure u key the cache by a unique field or fields you can't cache all query sets though only the results for a certain already known query.